# Is there a way to cluster an image based on colors and visualize that by using a for loop for example?

Tags: python, image-classification

I am trying to code the following image classification code:
https://www.thepythoncode.com/article/kmeans-for-image-segmentation-opencv-python

but my question is; is there a way to write a loop such that for each cluster that you use, you get a new image that blackens out this part of the image?

I was trying for example this:

```
for i in range(0,k):
    cluster = i
    masked_img[labels == cluster] = [0, 0, 0]
    masked_img[i] = masked_img[i].reshape(image.shape)
    plt.figure()
    plt.imshow(masked_img[i])
    plt.show()
```

with my initially loaded image and k=5 clusters, but what I want is the loop to give me 5 different images with the 5 individual clusters visualized. I don't get how I can manage to fix this, I hope someone else does!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your approach, I think if you just change `labels == cluster` to `labels != cluster`, it should work.

However, here is another way in Python/OpenCV.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read input and convert to range 0-1
image = cv2.imread('lake.png')
h, w, c = image.shape

# reshape to 1D array
image_2d = image.reshape(h*w, c).astype(np.float32)

# set number of colors
numcolors = 3
numiters = 10
epsilon = 1
attempts = 10

# do kmeans processing
criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, numiters, epsilon)
ret, labels, centers = cv2.kmeans(image_2d, numcolors, None, criteria, attempts, cv2.KMEANS_RANDOM_CENTERS)

# reconstitute 2D image of results
centers = np.uint8(centers)
newimage = centers[labels.flatten()]
newimage = newimage.reshape(image.shape)
cv2.imwrite("lake_kmeans.png", newimage)
cv2.imshow('new image', newimage)
cv2.waitKey(0)

k = 0
for center in centers:
    # select center color and create mask
    #print(center)
    layer = newimage.copy()
    mask = cv2.inRange(layer, center, center)

    # apply mask to layer 
    layer[mask == 0] = [0,0,0]
    cv2.imshow('layer', layer)
    cv2.waitKey(0)


    # save kmeans clustered image and layer 
    cv2.imwrite("lake_layer{0}.png".format(k), layer)
    k = k + 1
```

k-means result:

[image]

Layers:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, this looks very nice! :)