# I'm getting an error creating a mask using openCv inRange() function

Tags: python, opencv, k-means, image-segmentation

Im applying K-Means for Image Segmentation and using the ‘center’ variable to create a mask but im keep getting the `The lower boundary is neither an array of the same size and same type as src, nor a scalar in function 'inRange'` error.
Here's my code :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2

sample_image = cv2.imread('island.jpg')
img = cv2.cvtColor(sample_image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

twoDimage = img.reshape((-1,3))
twoDimage = np.float32(twoDimage)

criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 10, 1.0)
K = 3
attempts=10

ret,label,centers=cv2.kmeans(twoDimage,K,None,criteria,attempts,cv2.KMEANS_RANDOM_CENTERS)
centers = np.uint8(centers)
res = centers[label.flatten()]
result_image = res.reshape((img.shape))


k = 0
for center in centers:
    # select color and create mask
    print(center) # [ 82 135  57]
    layer = res.copy()
    mask = cv2.inRange(layer,center ,center)
```

when I run the code I get :

```
error: OpenCV(4.6.0) /io/opencv/modules/core/src/arithm.cpp:1741: error: (-209:Sizes of input arguments do not match) The lower boundary is neither an array of the same size and same type as src, nor a scalar in function 'inRange'
```

Comment: Make center a Numpy array.  Try center = np.array([center]). Be sure the values of your center are integers

Comment: @fmw42 i have tried it, but it still gives the same error. 
also, the values of my center are all integers, here's the output of my center variable : [ 32 156 200]

Comment: Post your image. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67462676/is-there-a-way-to-cluster-an-image-based-on-colors-and-visualize-that-by-using-a/67475088#67475088. Does that help?

Comment: @fmw42 i still dont know what i did wrong, but the answer you provided worked for me, thank you

Comment: I think you are placing extra brackets in res.rezhape((img.shape))